# Boot Windows 8 from SD Card

Tags: windows, macos, boot

My goal is to boot Windows 8 on my MacBook Air from an SD Card.

I came up with the idea after I purchased the [Nifty Minidrive.](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1342319572/the-nifty-minidrive) Since it added a whole 64 GB of expandable storage, I thought it would be a great idea to put Windows on there. Yes, I understand the Write limitations even with a Class 10 MicroSDXC, but I'm willing to live with that if there is some way I can make this setup work.

I've started with this [guide](http://www.weihermueller.de/mac/index.htm) on how to put Linux on an SD. In this guide, you divide up the SD into two partitions, one for the actual OS, and another small partition for rEFIt (I'm assuming everyone knows what rEFIt is, so moving on).

The rEFIt partition works perfectly, and is read by the OS fine. The problem is I am unsure on how to install Windows to the actual SD because of a few problems. I'm worried the setup is unable to read the SD as an installable source. How should I go about this? Should I clone an actual Windows 8 drive to the OS partition on my SD? Is there some software trick? Or should I just attempt to install normally?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make sure the SD is in NTFS format. If that is the case, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to install normally =)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know if this will work. Can you make the card bootable. I only know how to do that from windows like in when installing windows to a note book from a flash drive.
Run the following series of commands then to make a bootable card.
`diskpart` wait for diskpart.exe to start
`list disk` and select 
`select disk x` where x is the number of the disk you wish to make bootable in your case the one which has 64GB size.
`clean` 
`create partition primary` 
`active`
`format fs=ntfs` now try to install windows to it or if you wanted to use it for installing copy your installation cd to it.

Comment: This is **not an answer**. It's a comment at best.